# Rails 4 - Column exists but does not update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I have recently added a field "tag" to my blog app built in Rails 4. Below you can see the field appearing in the Edit view:

[image: rendered form]

But once I return to the Show view after editing, this does not appear:

[image: Post view]

When I check the database directly I can definitely see it exists:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(POSTS);
0|id|INTEGER|1||1
1|title|varchar(255)|0||0
2|body|text|0||0
3|created_at|datetime|0||0
4|updated_at|datetime|0||0
5|slug|varchar(255)|0||0
6|tag|varchar(255)|0||0
```

Can anyone suggest what is going on or how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Do you have the server logs showing any errors? That would help debug. Perhaps this is a problem with forgetting to include "tags" in your permitted params (assuming you are using strong params)

Comment: I had no idea what you said, but when I checked the controller for my posts, I found that `post_prams` did not have `:tag` included. Popped it in and there it is. Thanks sir! How do I set your response to be the answer?

Comment: I have posted an answer with more of an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 4 uses [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) by default. This means you have to explicitly whitelist params you wish to mass assign.

When adding a new attribute to a model, you have to remember to update the permitted params in you controller.

For example, in your case, you would need to make sure `:tags` are added like so:

```
class PostController < ActionController::Base    

  def update
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    post.update(post_params)
    redirect_to post
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :tag)
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a perfect explanation.